# Is a model matrix not a numeric matrix?

Tags: r

I have created a design matrix X using

```
X <- model.matrix( ~ age + BMI + sex, data=df)
```

and the result looks as I expect it to. I want to test for multicollinearity, so I'm using

```
library(mctest)
mctest(X, y)
```

which yields

```
Error in mctest(X, y) : X must be a numeric matrix
```

Am I missing something here?

Edit: Here's the output of str(). I've shortened it a bit, my actual model is way larger than the one shown above.

```
num [1:210, 1:41] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
- attr(*, "assign")= int [1:41] 0 1 2 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 ...
- attr(*, "contrasts")=List of 27
 ..$ Sex            : chr "contr.treatment"
[...]
 attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
 ..$ : chr [1:210] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 ..$ : chr [1:41] "(Intercept)" "age" "BMI" "Sex1" ...
- attr(*, "scaled:center")= Named num [1:41] 1 65.0048 25.9557 0.2857 0.0381 ...
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:41] "(Intercept)" "age" "BMI" "Sex1" ...
- attr(*, "scaled:scale")= Named num [1:41] 0 11.317 5.129 0.453 0.192 ...
 ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:41] "(Intercept)" "age" "BMI" "Sex1" ...
```

Comment: Yes. It' the same gibberish you get for a matrix.

Comment: Try `is.numeric(X)`. Without data I have tried with the buit-in dataset `iris` and I am getting a different error, *Error in eigen(R) : infinite or missing values in 'x'*.

Comment: is.numeric(X) is TRUE.